# Loading a new kernel in a chrooted environment

Tags: linux, kernel, multi-boot, chroot

Is it posible to load a new kernel while in a chrooted environment.  Say I have one linux distro and want to chroot into another and load its kernel

Comment: What you need to run another kernel is virtualization, not chroot. Take a look at Xen or KVM, or VMware.

Answer (score 2):

Not likely.  You are already running a kernel.  To have it load a second one based on a particular login doesn't sound possible or desirable.  With the proliferation of virtualization tools these days, I would think that's a more likely solution.